# Getting visitors detail for website in database but same ip address getting saved multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

This is to create database

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx`.`track`(`id_stat` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
                          `v_ip` varchar(15) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                          `v_time` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                          `v_ref` varchar(200) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                          `v_agent` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                          `v_url` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                           PRIMARY KEY (`id_stat`)
               ) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and this is php code but is not working . kindly tell me what mistake i am doing here

```
<?php
$stsip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$stagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$sturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'];
$stref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$stuser="abc";
$stpass = "thanks";
$sthost="localhost";

$stdb= "visitorsrecord";

$sttable="track";
$handle = mysql_connect("$sthost",$stuser,$stpass) or die("Connection Failure to Database");
mysql_select_db($stdb,$handle) or die ($stdb."Database not found.".$stuser);
mysql_query("insert into $sttable(v_time, v_ip, v_agent, v_url, v_ref) values(NOW(), '".$stsip."', '".$stagent."','".$sturl."', '".$stref."')");
mysql_close($handle);

?>
```

Now the code is working fine. but now I am facing problem is . if someone open the website then i am getting one entry in database but if he further opening then another entry is coming. but i want to record only unique ip address per day.

Comment: first check your database .table is created?

Comment: yes it is created successfully .thanks for reply

Comment: You can start by not using MySQL but mysqli instead. You should have already been bombarded with depreciation notices

Comment: So what actual errors are you getting (look in php error log)

Comment: database is created with table successfully but when i was trying with localhost then i got error message that database not found. but database with table is present. thanks for reply.

Comment: You code says : $sthost="what i will write here i do not know. "; Ask your database administrator. If you are that person, search the internet for for how install and connect to a database.

Comment: I need help for that. you kindly guide me. and provide any link you think is correct. thanks for reply

Comment: my code is working in xampp but it is not working live

Comment: This code has a significant SQL injection flaw in it - at present people can use a malicious agent string to run arbitrary SQL on your database. Look into escaping or parameterisation to combat this.

Comment: @halfer please show me your code to understand where is chance of sql injection attactk  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm offering here a partial answer, focussing on the SQL injection vulnerability in this code).

The first part is to reset the User Agent string in your browser. There are plugins for this, and in Firefox additionally you can visit `about:config` to see the internal settings, and it can be edited by hand here. Try resetting your browser to have a user agent string of `My Browser'` (note the unmatched quote mark).

Then run your code above. You'll effectively be executing this partial bit of SQL: `values(NOW(), '1.2.3.4', 'My Browser'', 'url', 'referrer')`. Look carefully at it - and please try it too - the unmatched quote mark has been injected in. In fact the referrer can also be easily faked to do this, and perhaps the URL field as well.

This example would just cause a database error. Depending on how you have configured your live server, this may cause errors to appear on-screen, which could give useful information to an attacker.

By luck and accident, it is not possible with this database library to run multiple SQL commands in the same query. That saves you from the most damaging kinds of injection, which would work as follows:

> referrer = `My Browser', '', ''); DELETE FROM track; --`

What would happen in this case, if the library were to allow it? Well, it would finish off the existing query up to the first semi-colon, then dutifully delete everything in the table it just inserted to. The `--` comment at the end then amends the remainder of the real query to a comment.

However, it is absolutely not recommended to rely on the library not being able to do this. It is bad enough that an error can be caused, but an attacker might inject and run MySQL functions, which may not be safe. For tables that are used to implement security features, such as login, they might inject their own admin accounts, etc.

The quickest solution here is to escape your input so it is not possible to do this. Try doing this to all your inputs:

```
$stagent = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

That will format special characters - in particular the apostrophe - so that they will be treated as part of the string, and not as a delimiter. Do this on all of your server variables, even if you don't think they need it - the worst that it can do is nothing.

Lastly, this approach of escaping-and-concatenation mostly will protect you, but in security terms *parameterisation* is thought to be significantly safer. Unfortunately, this library does not support it, and since it is deprecated anyway (and removed in PHP 7), it is worth moving to PDO/mysql or MySQLi when you get the chance.

Further reading: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)